# Does function binding have any concerns or issues in performance in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html

I wanted to know that when binding a function call in html, has any performance issue, rather if we use property binding.
I have tried,

```
<span class="alarm-count" ng-if="bindFun()">My bind</span>
```

whereas in my controller,
I have called it as,

```
$scope.bindFun = function(){return service.bindDataFun()};
```

Further, in service.

```
service.bindDataFun=function(){
    return true // On condition evaluation.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a big deal. The `ng-if` expression will be called in every digest (regardless if it is a function or not).

So having:

```
$scope.bindFun = true;
```

vs

```
$scope.bindFun = function() { return foo(); };
```

both are going to be checked in every digest, but certainly having to call two extra functions every time, will reduce the performance. I don't think it is a big deal, not that Javascript takes ages to call a function.

On the other hand, that is a pretty common pattern.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. 
But if we return some integer value from service, like
// In service
$scope.a=1;
service.bindDataFun = function() {
                    if($scope.a==1)
                         return ++$scope.a;
                     return $scope.a;        }
Then, how does the watcher get invoke to call digest() cylcle every time in infinite loop till TTL count.
Does this is also a common pattern and does not create any major performance issue??